# k8s service annotations not working on AWS LB

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-elb

I am running a cluster in EKS, with k8s 1.21.5

I know by default k8s has a Cloud Controller Manager which can be used to create Load balancers and by default it will create a classic LB in AWS.

I realize CLB are going away and I should use NLB or ALB and rather install the AWS Load Balancer controller instead but I want to work out why my annotations dont work.

What I am trying to do is setup a TLS listen using an ACM certificate because by default its all setup as TCP

Here are my annotations

```
#    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:aws:acm:<region>:<account>:certificate/<id>
#    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: ssl
#    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: <port>
```

I have followed the k8s docs here which specify which annotations to use https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#ssl-support-on-aws

And I have checked in the k8s code that these annotations are present

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.21.5/staging/src/k8s.io/legacy-cloud-providers/aws/aws.go#L162
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.21.5/staging/src/k8s.io/legacy-cloud-providers/aws/aws.go#L167
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.21.5/staging/src/k8s.io/legacy-cloud-providers/aws/aws.go#L181

When I create my service with these annotations, the service in k8s says pending

Can anyone tell me why it wont work or give me any insight?
What I have been doing is manually configuring the LB after its created, but I want to get away from doing that

Comment: what does your EKS cloud controller manager log say? Also is your role assigned to the EKS control plane have enough permissions to do ACM, ELB and bunch of other things?

Comment: Totally forgot about CP logging. So just enabled that and I am getting following error failed to ensure load balancer: CertificateNotFound: Server Certificate not found for the key: BUT the ARN is correct for my key. Does it matter the cert and my cluster are in different regions? I dont think ACM is in all regions at moment. BUT I can allocate that same cert manually via ELB UI

Answer (score 1):

@congbaoguier

Thanks for your advice to look at the logs, I was being a complete dummy. After enabling my logging on control plane I was able to see that there was an issue with my ACM ARN and weirdly I have no idea where I got that ARN from, what I check it in ACM it was WRONG *DOH*

Updating my ARN it now works, so thanks for the push to use my brain again :P